# Powershell + EWS Impersonation insufficient permission

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I get the following error -

```
Exception calling "Bind" with "2" argument(s): "The server to which the application is connected cannot impersonate the requested user due to insufficient permission."
```

Using the following code -

```
## Load Exchange web services DLL
## Download here if not present: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255472
$dllpath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
Import-Module $dllpath

## Creating Service Object
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)

## Setting up Admin Credentials with Impersonated Role Group rights
$user = "serviceAccount"
$pass = "P@55w0rd"
$service.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pass

## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server)
#$service.AutodiscoverUrl($AccountWithImpersonationRights ,{$true})
$EWSurl = "https://server.domain.ca/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
$service.URL = $EWSurl

## Setting up ImperSonated User
$service.ImpersonatedUserId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, "mailbox@domain.com")

#Connect to the Inbox and display basic statistics
$InboxFolder= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox, "mailbox@domain.com")
$Inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$InboxFolder)
Write-Host 'Total Item count for Inbox:' $Inbox.TotalCount
Write-Host 'Total Items Unread:' $Inbox.UnreadCount
```

Currently I'm just trying to do a simple connect.  The intention is then to download an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the Service Account your using "serviceAccount" doesn't have rights to Impersonate the user your trying to access. EWS Impersonation rights need to granted via RBAC see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx

Cheers
Glen